# How Can I Use The Xamarin Freely After "Xamarin For Everyone" Announcement?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin-studio, xamarin.mac

I have Xamarin Academic license for iOS and Android due to 19 May 2016. I have VS 2015 Enterprise license also. After the date, how can I use the Xamarin for freely on OS X and Windows as described at Build Day 2  ?

> **Visual Studio now includes Xamarin**
>
> As of today, we are including Xamarin in Visual Studio at no extra
>   cost.
>
> Xamarin will be in every edition of Visual Studio, including the
>   widely-available Visual Studio Community Edition, which is free for
>   individual developers, open source projects, academic research,
>   education, and small professional teams. Develop and publish native
>   apps for iOS and Android with C# or F# from directly within Visual
>   Studio with no limits on app size.
>
> For developers on the Mac, Xamarin Studio is now available as a
>   benefit of your Visual Studio Professional or Enterprise subscription.
>   Developers can use the newly-created Xamarin Studio Community Edition
>   for free.
>
> To begin developing iOS and Android apps with the full power of
>   Xamarin and C#, download Xamarin Studio or Xamarin for Visual Studio
>   today.

Thanks.

Comment: Download Visual Studio Update 2, and include Xamarin in the Updater. If that doesn't work, use the updater to update to the most recent build. https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/ide/change_updates_channel/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Windows:

If you do a fresh install you can add Xamarin while installing Visual Studio by selecting Custom installation and in features list selecting Xamarin. Below link gives a step by step installation process.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/mt613162.aspx

For existing VS users, below link can help install the Xamarin.

http://www.cazzulino.com/install-xamarin-2015-preview.html

For Mac:

Download and install the Xamarin for Mac and for licensing you can use the VS license details here.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/mac/

Answer (score 1):

Go to [download section](https://www.xamarin.com/download) of Xamarin and download the installer. Then run it and you're done! (You can install it on any version of Visual Studio 2015)