# Integrate Xamarin components into VS 2015 Professional?

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I have installed Visual Studio 2015 Professional and would like to know how/what should I download from the Xamarin website to integrate into VS 2015 Pro to develop Android apps with Xamarin.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How Can I Use The Xamarin Freely After "Xamarin For Everyone" Announcement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36359464/how-can-i-use-the-xamarin-freely-after-xamarin-for-everyone-announcement)

Answer (score 1):

Just download the universal [installer](https://www.xamarin.com/download) from their website

Answer (score 0):

During Visual Studio installation, you have the option to select C#/.NET(Xamarin) under Cross-Platform Development.

You can Modify/Repair the Visual Studio install and select Xamarin and any other components (e.g. Android SDK if it was not selected previously, although they can also be installed separately) and update the installation. Install details/reference [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt613162.aspx)